# Go TCP read is non blocking

Tags: c, tcp, go

I am trying to make a server and client in Go, I have managed to communicate with the server and client. But the problem I have is that the TCP read in golang is non-blocking.
What I would like to know if is it possible for the read in golang to be blocking like read in C.
Thank You

EDIT:

Here is the source code of the server:

```
func Init_tcp() *net.TCPListener {
    laddr, err := net.ResolveTCPAddr("tcp", ":4243")
    if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
    }
    tcp, err := net.ListenTCP("tcp", laddr)
    if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
    }
    return tcp
}

func main() {
    tcp := Init_tcp()
    conn, _ := tcp.Accept()
    data := make([]byte, 512)
    conn.SetNoDelay(false)
    for {
            conn.Read(data)
            fmt.Println(data)
    }
}
```

and my client:

```
func Init_tcp() *net.TCPConn {
    laddr, err := net.ResolveTCPAddr("tcp", "127.0.0.1:4243")
    if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
    }
    tcp, err := net.DialTCP("tcp", nil, laddr)
    if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
    }
    return tcp
}

func main() {
   tcp := Init_tcp()
   tcp.Write([]byte("hello world"))
}
```

Comment: Show your code, `*net.TCPConn` does block on `Read` -- with an optional timeout.

Comment: I just edited my post with my source

Comment: May have been initially unclear, but raises a real issue of how to handle partial data from `Read` (especially from network connections). Doesn't feel like a -2 as revised.

Comment: I think that your real problem is ignoring the errors from Read. Once your client exits, the write socket closes, the read will begin to return errors, resulting in what appears to be an infinite loop. Remember that Read can return data, a count AND an error in the same call. And you have to deal with all of it.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

`Reader`s can return partial data. From [the docs](http://golang.org/pkg/io/#Reader), "If some data is available but not len(p) bytes, Read conventionally returns what is available instead of waiting for more."

This is an issue in any language, even if something like this happened to work for you in C: TCP just provides a stream of bytes that can be written to any time. Single writes might, by design, be broken up into multiple packets for transmission, and there's no built-in signal to the receiver saying where a single write/message/request ends. The application has to figure out its own way to signal boundaries. That can mean delimiters (`\n`) or implicit or explicit byte counts (HTTP's `Content-Length` is an explicit one).

To read a specific number of input bytes, you want [`io.ReadAtLeast`](http://golang.org/pkg/io/#ReadAtLeast) or `io.ReadFull`. To read until some arbitrary condition is met you should just loop on the `Read` call as long as there is no error. (Then you may want to error out on on too-large inputs to prevent a bad client from eating server resources.) If you're implementing a text-based protocol you should consider [`net/textproto`](http://golang.org/pkg/net/textproto/), which puts a [`bufio.Reader`](http://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#Reader) in front of the connection so you can read lines. To limit how long you'll wait to finish reading (so that a misbehaving client can't leave a goroutine hanging and using memory, etc. forever), look at the [`net`](http://golang.org/pkg/net/) functions with `Deadline` in the name (which are related to the `Timeout` functions on the `Error` types). The [`context`](https://golang.org/pkg/context/) package helps manage timeouts, deadlines, and cancellation, and is especially useful if, for example, you're writing a complex server that's going to do many network operations every request.

The sample code has a possibly unrelated but important problem: it throws away errors from the `Read` and `Write`. That could mask simple problems and make them very hard to debug. If you have problems after accounting for partial reads, check all errors before asking for more help. Look at [`errcheck`](https://github.com/kisielk/errcheck/) to make sure mistakes like this don't get into production.