Sending a log/slog to an API endpoint in golang
Assuming this code:
import (
    slog "log/slog"
...
)

func main(){
    v1 := "10"
    v2 := "bada"
    // logger01 := slog.New(slog.NewJSONHandler(os.Stdout, nil))
    logger01 := slog.New(slog.NewTextHandler(os.Stderr, nil))

// need help here to send logger01 to an API endpoint, such as Localhost.

}

Instead of sending to console, I want to send a JSON or a string to local host API endpoint.
Ideally, Ideally, I would DIAL local host and send an io.writer...  something like that.

Implement a Handler that does that, and pass it to slog.New()

could someone do an example of how I would implement a slog to a handler that will send to a socket over tcp?

In my opinion, you can pass net.Conn to slog.NewJSONHandler as io.Writer. So you can utilize the socket programming in Go.
I write the simple example code.
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "log/slog"
    "net"
    "time"
)

func loggingServer() {
    listener, err := net.Listen("tcp", "localhost:50002")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err.Error())
    }

    go func() {
        for {
            conn, err := listener.Accept()
            if err != nil {
                log.Printf("failed to accept connection: %v\n", err)
            }
            go handlerConn(conn)
        }
    }()
}

func handlerConn(conn net.Conn) {
    reader := bufio.NewReader(conn)
    for {
        msg, err := reader.ReadString('\n')
        if err != nil {
            log.Printf("faild to read from conn: %v\n", err)
            break
        }
        fmt.Println("In loggingServer: ", msg)
    }
}

func main() {
    go loggingServer()

    conn, err := net.Dial("tcp", "localhost:50002")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err.Error())
    }

    logger := slog.New(slog.NewJSONHandler(conn, nil))
    logger.Info("Test the log to the connection")
    logger.Info("It works well")


    time.Sleep(5 * time.Second)
}

It shows logs at the server side
In loggingServer:  {"time":"2024-04-10T10:10:41.93804+09:00","level":"INFO","msg":"Test the log to the connection"}

In loggingServer:  {"time":"2024-04-10T10:10:46.938184+09:00","level":"INFO","msg":"It works well"}

I didn't include the code for closing the connection but you should consider it.

FYI, f you decide to use socket programming, this post can be helpful (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26999615/go-tcp-read-is-non-blocking). Read() of Conn is not blocked but ReadString can be blocked until it meets its delimeter

There's no need to do socket programming as the http.ResponseWriter argument of net/http request handlers is an io.Writer as well so one can fully leverage the stock HTTP stack and send logs directly to the client. What I wrote in my comments to the question still applies, of course.

I see. But I can't imagine what you said yet. Please show your code if possible.

Oh, please disregard what I said: I think I have misinterpreted the OP's question: they ostensibly want to perform an HTTP POST or HTTP PUT request and stream log data there–at least that's how I interpret «…send a JSON or a string to local host API endpoint» (junior folks these days usually use the term "API" to refer to web services). But then basically what they need to do is to construct a net/http.Request whose Body is set to the read end of an io.Pipe whose write end is passed to an log/slog logger instance. Well, that is if we talk about streaming. The question is lacking detail
